# Scraping asb.net site does not work when using a function in selenium in python

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I want to scrape a .net website, i make this code

```
from scrapy import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class BoursakuwaitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'boursakuwait'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'second.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    }
    start_urls = ['https://casierjudiciaire.justice.gov.ma/verification.aspx']

    def parse(self, no_response):
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        browser.get('https://casierjudiciaire.justice.gov.ma/verification.aspx')
        time.sleep(10)
        response = Selector(text=browser.page_source)
```

when i use the function parse the code does not work but if i use just the class like this :

```
import time

import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class BoursakuwaitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'boursakuwait'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'second.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    }
    start_urls = ['https://casierjudiciaire.justice.gov.ma/verification.aspx']


    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    browser.get('https://casierjudiciaire.justice.gov.ma/verification.aspx')
    time.sleep(10)
    response = Selector(text=browser.page_source)
```

The code work correclty.
But for me i want to use the function (the first code) i don't know where is the problem.
please any help.

Comment: What error do you see? A copy of the error message or a screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the website of Moroccan's Ministry of Justice is so old that your programme can't handle it. According to [this thread](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5491), you'll need to downgrade your `cryptography` and `pyOpenSSL` packages to handle the website:

```
pip install --upgrade cryptography==36.0.2
pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
```

If that somehow didn't work, then try installing all of the followings:

```
Scrapy       : 2.6.1
lxml         : 4.8.0.0
libxml2      : 2.9.4
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.6.0
w3lib        : 1.22.0
Twisted      : 22.4.0
```

Comment: No is not Working

Comment: How do you run your spider? What error do you see? Normally, just `cd` into the folder that your python file is in, then `scrapy runspider your_python_file.py`.

Comment: for runing the spider i use scrapy crawl boursakuwait

Comment: there is no error but during the execution the parse method which contains the launch of the site does not work. the browser simply closes

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I've edited my answer. Try the above, see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but he is not working. This problem is for asp.net website , if i try another website (not an asp.net website) the method of parse work fine

Comment: What error do you see in your terminal? It'd be strange if the terminal shows nothing at all.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', '', 'unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled')]>]
2022-10-04 09:34:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Comment: Yeah, that's the exact error I've got. Did downgrading `cryptography` and `pyOpenSSL` in the terminal do nothing at all?

Comment: nothing at all I have already installed it without any result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248537/discussion-between-duc-nguyen-and-med-maliari).